# Why do 2-1 muxes forming 4-1 mux have common selector?

Tags: multiplexer

Why is s0 common for both 2-1 multiplexers? Shouldn't each one have it's own data selector? Doesn't such setup remove some of possible logical outputs from multiplexers, if s0 value is same for both? I'm pretty new to multiplexers and probably don't understand the logic behind it yet.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it. S1 selects whether you want the top or the bottom dual selector from the left. S0 selects whether you want the top or bottom input of the respective dual selector. All 4 inputs are addressable.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a multiplexer is that the output Y can be one of 2^n inputs, where n is the number of select bits. In this case, n is 2.

Even if you were to give an additional select bit, i.e. S2 to the top mux, you would just be increasing the overhead of selecting your input from 2 select bits to 3 (S0 S1 S2), while not increasing the amount of selectable input bits (4).